# Meteor BrowserPolicy enable 'blob:' origins

Tags: javascript, meteor, content-security-policy

I have enabled Content Security Policy meteor package meteor/browser-policy-common

Now I'm getting this error from ostrio:files related to CSP

> Refused to create a worker from
>   'blob:http://localhost:3000/ef628f55-736b-4b36-a32d-b1056adfaa8c'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' http://fonts.googleapis.com
>   https://fonts.googleapis.com http://fonts.gstatic.com
>   https://fonts.gstatic.com http://code.ionicframework.com
>   https://code.ionicframework.com". Note that 'worker-src' was not
>   explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

My actual browser-policy-common config looks like this

```
import { BrowserPolicy } from 'meteor/browser-policy-common';
// e.g., BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll( 's3.amazonaws.com' );
// BrowserPolicy.content.allowFontOrigin("data:");

BrowserPolicy.framing.disallow();
BrowserPolicy.content.disallowInlineScripts();
BrowserPolicy.content.disallowEval();
BrowserPolicy.content.allowInlineStyles();
BrowserPolicy.content.allowFontDataUrl();

const trusted = [
  'fonts.googleapis.com',
  'fonts.gstatic.com',
  'code.ionicframework.com',
];

_.each(trusted, (origin) => {
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll(origin);
});
```

Can you tell me which config should I change to allow ostrio:files blob:http://localhost:3000/... to work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To allow `blob:` origins, you can add this:

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('blob:');
```

Meteor doesn’t provide a mechanism for more specifically allowing `blob:` just for `worker-src`.

Comment: THANKS! PS Always found Meteor docs way too terse. A keyword search for allowOriginForAll doesn't show anything at Meteor guide. Stackoverflow to the rescue!